# Is there an option to right align text in messageBottom attribute of DataTables pdf export?

Tags: javascript, datatables, pdf-generation

I've created a pdf export using Datatables and I am displaying a message under the exported table using `messageBottom`. The problem is that it is automatically left aligned, and I would like the value to be right aligned, underneath the last column of the exported table. Is there a way to achieve this? I've looked through the Datatable pdfHtml5 documentation but I can't seem to figure out how to adjust the alignment of text in `messageBottom` or `messageTop`.

Here is my code initializing the table:

```
var table = $('#exampleTable').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
         {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            messageBottom: function() {
               return 'message to be displayed at bottom'
            },
            customize: function ( doc ) {
            /* here I am aligning text in a column to the right */
            var rowCount = table.rows().count() + 1;
            for (i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
               doc.content[2].table.body[i][3].alignment = 'right';
            };
         }
      }
   ]
} );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the version of datable that I am using I have solved it this way. 'messageBottom' uses the style 'message', so adding the following line in the customize has solved the problem for me.

```
doc.styles.message.alignment = "right";
```

The problem with this solution is that 'messageTop' also uses the style 'message' so it will also align to the right but in my case I am only using 'messageBottom'. I don't know if there is a better way.

My example:

```
{
    extend: 'pdf',
    messageBottom: function() { 
        return "\n\nTOTAL VENCIMIENTO: "+$('#header-vcto-total span').text()+"\n"
    },
    customize: function(doc) {
        /** this line changes the alignment of 'messageBottom' and 'messageTop' **/
        doc.styles.message.alignment = "right";

        doc.content[1].table.widths = [ '40%',  '25%', '17.5%', '17.5%'];
        var rowCount = doc.content[1].table.body.length;
        for (i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
            doc.content[1].table.body[i][1].alignment = 'center';
            doc.content[1].table.body[i][2].alignment = 'center';
            doc.content[1].table.body[i][3].alignment = 'right';
            doc.content[1].table.body[i][3].text += ' €';
        };
    }    
}
```

I hope you find it useful.
A greeting.

Comment: Thanks for the help that works! I've found another solution which is to use ```doc.content.push``` to simply append text to the bottom of the pdf which you can then format. I'll create another answer to show how it can be used

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @zhexirox does right align message bottom, only issue is it also aligns the message top the same. If you just want to align / format content beneath the table you can use `doc.content.push`
Here is an example:

```
customize: function(doc) {
   doc.content.push( {
      margin: [15, 20, 0, 0 ],
      alignment: 'left',
      text: 'example message'
   });
}
```